# Tensorflow saved_model in flask app causes gunicorn WORKER TIMEOUT

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, gunicorn

I know this is a pretty frequently asked question, but I don't see anyone with the same source of error I've pinpointed.

So I have a flask app which does prediction using Tensorflow. I load the model using [`my_model = tf.saved_model.load(path_to_model)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load),instantiate the service class with `my_service=Service(my_model)`, test run it using `my_service.predict(sample_user_input)` (**note this works**). And then start flask, so basically:

```
#API.py
my_model = tf.saved_model.load(path_to_model)
my_service=Service(my_model)
assert my_service.predict(sample_user_input, "neuralNets").is_ok  #this passes
@app.route('/')
def foo(user_input):
    results = my_service.predict(user_input, "neuralNets")        #this does not
    return results.toJson()
```

I can pinpoint the source of error to [`tf_model.signatures['predict']`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#savedmodels_from_estimators) in the `.predict` method. Because when `.predict` receives "linear" instead of "neuralNets" as arg, everything works. And the only difference between those two is `tf_model.signatures`.

I can also confirm this is a gunicorn issue, because if I just run `python3 API.py` use Flask's builtin server, which is pretty crap, it works fine.

So I followed [this](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1801) thread, and played with gunicorn configs, I tried:

```
--timeout=120
--worker-class=gthread/gevent
--threads 2/3/4...
--workers=1 + multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
--preload
```

Nothing works. So here I am, any help is appreciated.
Also I've reproduced the same result on two different ubuntu machines and docker image running on k8s. So this is definitely not a "just reboot" problem.

Comment: can you do `my_model.predict` instead of `my_service.predict`. Then you know it's an issue with the `Service` class with `gunicorn`, and not with `tensorflow` and `gunicorn`? Do you do some `threading` stuff in this `Service` class?